# How to pass an empty list to argparse in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to pass two lists using argparse, I do not have any problems when both the lists contain some elements but sometimes one of the lists can be an empty list. How can I handle this case?

**This is my code**

```
# calculate the median 
import argparse 

def findMedianSortedArrays(nums1, nums2):
    combined_list = nums1 + nums2
    sorted_list = sorted(combined_list)
    list_len = len(sorted_list)
    mid_index = len(sorted_list) // 2

    # case 1 - single element
    if list_len == 1:
        return sorted_list[0]

    # case 2 - odd length list
    if list_len % 2 != 0:
        return sorted_list[mid_index]

    # case 3 - even length list
    if list_len % 2 == 0:
        mean_lower_upper = (sorted_list[mid_index - 1] + sorted_list[mid_index]) / 2
        return mean_lower_upper

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("nums1", help="first list")
    parser.add_argument("nums2", help="second list")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    nums1 = [int(num) for num in args.nums1.split(",")]
    nums2 = [int(num) for num in args.nums2.split(",")]

    print("Array 1:", nums1)
    print("Array 2:", nums2)
    print("\nMedian of sorted array:", findMedianSortedArrays(nums1, nums2))
```

**Test cases that need to be passed -**

```
# Case 1 - I have no problems here
Input: nums1 = [1,2], nums2 = [3,4]
Output: 2.50000
Explanation: merged array = [1,2,3,4] and median is (2 + 3) / 2 = 2.5.

# case 2 - need help here
Input: nums1 = [], nums2 = [1]
Output: 1.00000

# case 3 - and here
Input: nums1 = [2], nums2 = []
Output: 2.00000
```

**the way I am passing the arguments**

```
python 04_median_of_two_sorted_arrays.py 1,2 3,4

# output - 
Array 1: [1, 2]
Array 2: [3, 4]

Median of sorted array: 2.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `"".split(",")` returns a list consisting of an empty string, and an empty string is not a valid integer. Using `if num` in the list comprehension it will ignore any empty strings returned by `split`.

```
    nums1 = [int(num) for num in args.nums1.split(",") if num]
```

Do the same for `nums2`.

Comment: This solves the problem but I also have to change the arguments `nums1` and `nums2` to optional arguments like `--nums1` and `--nums2` and pass the arguments like this `python 04_median_of_two_sorted_arrays.py  --nums1= --nums2=1`. Without these modeifications, I am getting errors.

Comment: The best solution for empty arguments depends on how you are calling the script (OS, shell, other script, etc) and may be affected by shell expansion. Making the parameters optional is one solution. Using bash you can pass an empty parameter by using 2 quote characters with nothing between them such as `python 04_median_of_two_sorted_arrays.py "" 3,4`.